# Installed Microsoft Service with success, but doesn't see on service list

Tags: c#, service, installutil

i need an help.
I follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services) to install microsoft service, with success, but I don't see in the service list.

My service:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }
}
```

There's is other mode to install a service ? Or i'm wrong somethink ?

my response from developer command tools:

> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of the log file for the
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.InstallLog.
>   Installing assembly
>   'C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    assemblypath =
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe
>   logfile =
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.InstallLog
>   No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute
>   could be found in the
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe
>   assembly.
>
> The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is
>   beginning. See the contents of the log file for the
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.InstallLog.
>   Committing assembly
>   'C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    assemblypath =
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe
>   logfile =
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.InstallLog
>   No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute
>   could be found in the
>   C:\projects\SimPortalService\SimPortalService\bin\Debug\SimPortalService.exe
>   assembly. Remove InstallState file because there are no installers.
>
> The Commit phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.

Comment: How do you know the install was successful?

Comment: Did you refresh the service list?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes..i've refreshed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have skipped an important step from the article:

> In order to use the steps in this article, you first need to add a service installer to your Windows Service. See [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer).

Your service doesn't have an installer, so `installutil` has no work to do as it reports:

> No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found

So, create an installer for your service.

Comment: I've added ad installer, but how to do to connect the service with installer in the same solution ?